# How to use an icon/image in the middle of a sentence using css/html

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement an icon in the middle of a sentence using html/css.

After trying a while, and searching I decided to ask instead.

Basically I have a sentence based off of a specific conditional. I'm just going to display the outcome of the conditional

```
%h5 {{ location.name }} <span class = "otherTest">:D</span><span class = "test"> YEAH BABY, THIS IS A PRIORITY!!!!! </span>
```

With my CSS I have

```
.test{
  color: #AA8D7C;
}

.otherTest{
  background: url(/assets/icons/location.png);
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 5px;
  widows: 5px;
  z-index: 55;
}
```

I have an icon that is attached to the `otherTest` div that is not showing up with what I have right now.  Does anybody know what I am missing with this one right here?

Comment: does the image work?

Comment: @Jeff that won't break it, their code works fine https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OmWXNm

Comment: @MichaelCoker ah, ok. Wasn't aware of that! Thanks! (deleted my last wrong comment)

Comment: OP maybe you need a background-size or background-position? Check the codepen in my previous comment. Your code works fine. Maybe the visible part of `location.png` isn't in the top 5x5 corner.

Comment: Can you show your folder structure?

Comment: Are you sure you want `widows: 5` and not `width: 5px` ? widows doesn't make sense here.

Comment: Ok, after looking through what you wonderful people have suggested, (the codepen was very helpful) i've realized something kinda weird. 

in the span where the icon is to be if I have something inside it, the icon appears, but if I do not, it does not.  So if it is <span class = "otherTest"></span> nothing will appear, but if it is <span class = "otherTest">:D </span> the icon will appear behind the :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use image as empty element's BACKGROUND.
You can fix it by setting element to inline-block and setting its dimensions.

```
.otherTest{
  background: url(/assets/icons/location.png);
    display:inline-block;
    width:5px;
    height:5px;
```

OR in my opinion the better way is to use **img** element instead of span with background.
for example:
CSS

```
.otherTest{
  display:inline-block;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
}
```

HTML

```
%h5 {{ location.name }} <img src="/assets/icons/location.png" class = "otherTest" alt=':D'><span class = "test"> YEAH BABY, THIS IS A PRIORITY!!!!! </span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this is exactly what I was looking for, I really appreciate it!